# Fresh React-Native project show white screen

Tags: android, react-native

I started a new `react-native` project, but the latest `init` shows me a white screen.

On old `react-native` project, i don't have this problem.

Kindly guide me how to fix this issue.

You can see my script :

```
#!/bin/bash
JAVA_HOME=$(grep JAVA_HOME .env | cut -d '=' -f2)
ANDROID_HOME=$(grep ANDROID_HOME .env | cut -d '=' -f2)

rm -rf .cache
export JAVA_HOME
export ANDROID_HOME
export PATH=${PATH}:$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools

node ./node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js run-android
node ./node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start -- --reset-cache
```

Thank you community !

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the latest native react it is like that.

first, run:

```
react-native start
```

then run

```
  react-natve run-android
```

This happens because npm is not immediately run the first time.

Comment: Arf, yes in deed. Thank you !